# Using Laravel Exists Validation with a condition specified with a function

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a model where I am attempting to use a exists validation rule like

```
public static $rules =  ['item' => 'exists:items,item,company_id,\Auth::user()->active_company',
                          'location' => 'exists:locations,location,company_id,\Auth::user()->active_company',
            ];
```

This validation rule is always failing.

```
        $validation = Validator::make($this->attributes, static::$rules);
```

If I modify the rule for the specific `user->active_company`, it works.

```
public static $rules =  ['item' => 'exists:items,item,company_id,17',
                          'location' => 'exists:locations,location,company_id,17',
            ];
```

It seems as if the function `\Auth::user()->active_company` isn't being evaluated when the rules are being checked.  All of the examples I've seen use a constant rather than a function.

Will this work with laravel validation or do I need to take a different strategy?

Comment: Nobody knows anything for sure without trying it first, did you try it? And what happened?

Comment: @davejal -Sure did.  "This validation rule is always failing." That's why I wrote the question - I tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encapsulation of the rules in single quotes means that the contents are taken literally. This means that the validation rule is looking for a company ID which is literally '\Auth::user()->active_company' as opposed to the output of that, perhaps 1 for the sake of example.

See the [single quoted strings manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

There are few ways you could do it:

- Break out of the quotes and concatenate the two strings with a period (.)

  ```
  public static $rules = [
      'item'     => 'exists:items,item,company_id,'.\Auth::user()->active_company,
      'location' => 'exists:locations,location,company_id,'.\Auth::user()->active_company,
  ];
  ```
- Write active_company to a variable and break out of the quotes and concatenate the two strings with a period (.)

  ```
  $activeCo = \Auth::user()->active_company;

  public static $rules = [
      'item'     => 'exists:items,item,company_id,'.$activeCo,
      'location' => 'exists:locations,location,company_id,'.$activeCo,
  ];
  ```
- Write active_company to a variable and use double quotes as variables are expanded/interpreted inside double ones. "$activeCo" or "{$activeCo}" will work

  ```
  $activeCo = \Auth::user()->active_company;

  public static $rules = [
      'item'     => "exists:items,item,company_id,{$activeCo}",
      'location' => "exists:locations,location,company_id,{$activeCo}",
  ];
  ```

Comment: Thank you @ben-swinburne . This got me where I needed to go. The string concatenation method worked - with one caveat: I had to move my `rules` array _inside_ my validation function.  
I kept getting
```
[Sat Dec 19 10:31:56 2015] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$activeCo' (T_VARIABLE) in /Users/beauraines/projects/ezplan/app/models/Item_locations.php on line 11
```
when I would attempt to define the `rules` array inside my Class. 

I'll be able to maintain the flexibility of my `isValid()` function by making the it `isValid($rules)` and define my rules before calling the function.

Comment: Ah, apologies, that makes sense. I'd not spotted that the `public static` meant you were defining properties of a class and therefore creating `$activeCo` there wouldn't work! Glad you've got it sorted.